# Validate textbox value from external object list

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

Hello and thank you for reading, I'm new to fluent validation, I have a Blazor server application with a form and a single textbox, my model is something like this:

```js
namespace ITT_OneTeam.ViewModels
{
    public class SaveView
    {
        public string? ViewName { get; set; }
    }

    public class SaveViewValidator : AbstractValidator<SaveView>
    {
        public SaveViewValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(SaveView => SaveView.ViewName).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please enter the Name to be used.");
        }
    }


}
```

as you can see, I created a class called SaveView with a single field called ViewName and then below I created a validation class.

THE CHALLENGE I have is that I will get a list of values from browser storage (not a database) and I would like to check if the value on the textbox exists already in that list, if so, then return an error but I could not find any information on these 2 things:

a) pass the list to the validator class to do the check or

b) when the submit method is executed, add an error on the fly to the validation object and avoid the submit...

Thank you beforehand for any help you may bring!

Answer (score 0):

Answering for point a, you can use 2 approaches.

1 (**list is model property**):

```
public class SaveView
{
    public string? ViewName { get; set; }

    #region For Validation Only
    public List<string> ExistingNamesForValidation { get; set; } // set this property to each model before it would be validated
    #endregion
}

public class SaveViewValidator : AbstractValidator<SaveView>
{
    public SaveViewValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(m => m.ViewName)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please enter the Name to be used.")
            .Must((m,p) => m.ExistingNamesForValidation.Contains(p)).WithMessage("Please use name from given list.");
    }
}
```

As written in comment, you have to set list in each model object before validation being performed.

and 2 (**list is encapsulated to separate service**):

```
public class MyNamesListService
{
    public MyNamesListService() // parameterless constructor allows service to be resolved by dependency injection
    {
        this.existingNames = /* get names list from HttpContext of web request */;
    }
    
    private List<string> existingNames;

    public bool Contains(string name)
    {
        return existingNames.Contains(name);
    }
}

public class SaveViewValidator : AbstractValidator<SaveView>
{
    public SaveViewValidator(MyNamesListService namesService)
    {
        RuleFor(m => m.ViewName)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please enter the Name to be used.")
            .Must(prop => namesService.Contains(prop)).WithMessage("Please use name from given list.");
    }
}
```

For this case you have to register service in your dependency injection environment.